# Unable to connect SDL Tridion content manager from Visio

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to connect SDL Tridion content manager using visio to open/save workflows, am getting the below error message, can you please help me on this?

*The request failed with HTTP status 407: proxy authentication required (The ISA server requires the authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the web proxy filter is denied).*

Comment: Which Visio version? Which Tridion version?

Comment: SDL Tridion 2011 GA and Microsoft Visio 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have some form of HTTP proxy running on your network which is preventing you from making a direct call to the CMS using the visio client. Could that be the case?

To test this, you might consider installing Visio on the CMS server itself, and trying to connect using a localhost or 127.0.0.1 address (these should bypass any proxies) rather than the DNS entry based name that you are using now.

If that works, we may be able to find a solution for connecting remotely.

Comment: Chris, Thank you very much for your answer. I was able to connect the CMS using the visio client from my home PC.

Comment: If this solved your answer, please consider up-voting and accepting the answer. 

Also if you are active in the SDL Tridion community, please consider committing to the Area 51 proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 so that we can get a dedicated SDL Tridion Q&A area. 

Thanks in advance

Chris